# How to validate a manifest of an SPFx webpart to publish it to Marketplace?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm now researching publication of the solution to Marketplace/AppSource. Here it's said that I can do that with an SPFx app, and as I understand, webparts are one of possible solution types:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/publish-to-marketplace-overview

Then they say to refer to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/checklist (which is for "Office store apps", I'm still struggling with the number of terms when it comes to MS platform) and in the paragraph 3 it's said that I should verify my manifest.

Is this even applicable to SPFx applications? And if it is - how do I validate it? I don't have any XML manifests in my project (generated by `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`).

I tried to pass this manifest to the verification tool: `sharepoint/solution/debug/AppManifest.xml` and it even recognized it as something similar to what it wants but then I get the following error:

```
Error #1: 
Wrong Package: Your package does not match submission type.

The manifest is not valid.
```

Comment: All SPFx web part solutions have the manifest file inside `src/webparts/<WebPartName>` folder with name in format `WebPartName.manifest.json`. Can you try using this? Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is a JSON manifest and yes, I have it, but the verification tool does not recognize it